# How find the of minimum $ab+bc+\frac{\sqrt{2}}2ac$ for $a^2+b^2=4,b^2+c^2=8$

Tags: inequality, maxima-minima

let $a,b,c$ are real numbers and such $a^2+b^2=4,b^2+c^2=8$, find the minimum of
$$ab+bc+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}ac$$

if this problem ask find the maximum 
we  can use $AM-GM$
$$ab+bc+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}ac=\dfrac{1}{Ax}Aa\cdot xb+\dfrac{1}{Bz}Bb\cdot zc+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2Cv}va\cdot Cc\le \dfrac{1}{Ax}(A^2a^2+x^2b^2)+\dfrac{1}{Bz}(B^2b^2+z^2c^2)+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2Cv}(v^2a^2+C^2c^2)$$

But  for mimimum I can't solve it.Thank you

for mimimum  I have some idea
let $$a=2\cos{x},b=2\sin{x},b=2\sqrt{2}\cos{y},c=2\sqrt{2}\sin{y}$$
and $\sin{x}=\sqrt{2}\cos{y}$
then $$ab+bc+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}ac=4\sin{x}\cos{x}+4\sqrt{2}\sin{x}\cos{y}+4\sin{y}\cos{x}$$

my nice methods

$$ab+bc+\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}ac=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}(a+\sqrt{2}b+c)^2-3\sqrt{2}$$

Comment: See the huge and complex solution in terms of roots of polynomials of higher degrees obtained with Mathematica [here](http://rapidshare.com/files/474289857/OP.pdf) as an exported PDF file.

Comment: See the numerical solution obtained with Maple by $$ DirectSearch:-GlobalSearch(a*b+b*c+(1/2)*sqrt(2)*a*c, \{a^2+b^2 = 4, b^2+c^2 = 8\}):$$ $$[[-4.2426407302032, [a = -.605847245180419, b = 1.90602969015315, c = -2.08974899972977], 1203], $$ $$[ -4.24264072959487,[a = 1.90604189905156, b = .605808830413558, c = -2.76278767211529],  2197],$$ $$ -4.24264072950065, [a = -1.90604163386125, b = -.605809665561305, c = 2.76278748876704], 1380], $$ $$-4.24264072905823,[a = .605811571196014, b = -1.90604102804011, c = 2.08973865774724], 1542]]$$

Comment: I think Mathematica solves the system of 5 equations formed with the Lagrange multipliers, reducing the one to an equation of higher degree.

Comment: The answer, btw, is $-3 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @ Robert : Why do you think so? Can you identify $a, b,$ and $c$?

Comment: The parametrization of the intersection of the two cylinders reduces the problem to two variables. Its solution can be reduced to an equation of degree 4. I have never seen any application of [the explicit formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) for its solutions. It makes no principal difference with the solution of the algebraic system in 5 unknowns $a, b,c, \mu, \lambda.$

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a job for Lagrange multipliers...
let $$F(a,b,c,\lambda,\mu) = ab + bc + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} ac + \lambda (a^2 + b^2 - 4) + \mu(b^2 + c^2 - 8)$$
and solve $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial a} = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial b} = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial c} = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda} = \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial \mu} = 0$

Comment: Thank you,I think this problem have other nice methods,Thank you

Comment: oh,Thank I have find nice methods,Thank you everyone